# Select 2 how to add color badge in option value

Tags: bootstrap-5, jquery-select2

I use select2 library and I try add badge color in option. But  this badge is not displayed.

```
<select id="select2B" class="form-select" style="width: 60%;">
    <option label="Choose one"></option>
    <?php foreach ($groupedStatuses as $group_name => $statusesGroup): ?>
        <optgroup label="<?= $group_name; ?>">
            <?php foreach ($statusesGroup as $status): ?>
                <?php
                $selected = ($status['status_id'] == $order->status) ? 'selected' : '';
                ?>
                <option value="<?= $status['status_id']; ?>" <?= $selected; ?>>
                    <span class="badge" style="background-color: <?= $status['status_color']; ?>">
                        <?= $status['status_name']; ?>
                    </span>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>



<script>
  // With search
      $('#select2B').select2({
        placeholder: 'Choose one'
      });

      $('#select2B').one('select2:open', function(e) {
        $('input.select2-search__field').prop('placeholder', 'Search...');
      });

      </script>
```

Can anyone help me how to display this color badge directly in option select?